# xubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 stuck during install on cups-server-common

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 13.10

I'm in the middle of upgrading to 13.10 but it has been stuck on installing cups-server-common all day long!!!  What would be the best thing to do without compromising my system???

Answer (score 1):

Well I seemed to figure out what to do. In a panic in the past, while upgrading when it froze I would reboot and than would be unable to log back into my system.

First in terminal I entered

```
pkill -U username
```

logged back in

next in terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

(since updating was locked by another process)

lastly

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on user207943's post so I am adding a full reply.

I had a similar problem on a 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade (Ubuntu not Xubuntu, and tex-common not cups). The method of user207943 worked to finish the install, however, for me I found that most of the upgrade was still unfinished. This took me a while to solve, but in the end was simple, so I thought I would share just in case someone finds this page on a google (like I did). I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to finish upgrading packages. This looked like everything was now done (If I paid more attention I would have seen that certain packages like linux-generic were NOT upgraded). Then, after a restart I found I had no network devices available (neither wireless or Ethernet). Eventually I found the solution was that I needed to run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After a restart 13.10 seems to be fine. Two simple commands, about 3 hours of my life wasted finding the second one :(