# Upgrading Ubuntu to version 13.10 hangs

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I'm upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 and the installation is hanging[image]

What steps can I take to rollback the upgrade?
Is it safe to shut down my machine?

Comment: neither its safe nor it will work for sure, fresh new installation is always better than upgrade if you don’t want to experience errors. If this already had unpacked the packages means your ubuntu will be no more after this shutdown shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the upgrade to 13.10. I solved it using a modified method of that that was presented by user207943 in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365351/xubuntu-13-04-to-13-10-stuck-during-install-on-cups-server-common/388088#388088).

Press Ctrl+Alt+T to get a terminal and log out using the command

```
pkill -U username
```

log back in, open the terminal again and unlock the update with:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally to finish run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After restarting mine was fine. (I had many restarts between the configure line and the other two lines. I was trying to fix issues with unfinished upgrades which caused my network devices not to be recognised (among other problems). Everything failed, until I ran the upgrade commands which solved everything.) I think you may be able to run just dist-upgrade rather than upgrade then dist-upgrade. I don't know but the above method seemed to work.

Comment: This could have well been the solution. In the meantime I had to re-install 13.10.